# How do I resolve this problem; I keep geting this error -411 Length Required: Spring boot 3.2.0-M3 example

Tags: spring-boot

How do I resolve this problem; I keep geting this error -411 Length Required: Spring boot 3.2.0-M3 example

```java
public AccessToken accessToken() {
        
        var subscriberKey="exxxx";
        var authorization="Basic " +Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(
                String.format("%s:%s", "xxxxxxx",
                        "yyyyyy").getBytes()
                );
                return RestClient.create().post().
              uri("https://sandbox.momodeveloper.mtn.com/collection/token/")                    //.contentLength((authorization+subscriberKey).getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8).length)
                        .headers(h -> {
                            h.add("Authorization",authorization);
                            h.add("Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key", subscriberKey);
                            h.add("Content-Length", "0");
                        })
                        .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED)
                    .retrieve()
                    .body(AccessToken.class);

            }
```

Caused by: org.springframework.web.client.HttpClientErrorException: 411 Length Required:

Comment: And what is the question?

Comment: The request uses POST but the API has no body. I added a body to the request as a workarround and it is now working.

Comment: You are setting `Content-Length` to 0. Just remove that header.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please don't just throw your error messages at us but give us a little explanation about what you want to achieve, your configuration, etc. At least, ask a concrete question, [here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) is a little how-to. On the one hand, this will make it easier (or possible at all) for us to help you solve your problem, on the other hand it makes us feel less mis-used as robots...

Answer (score 0):

You are setting Content-Length to 0. Just remove that header.